# Регулярные выражения: вывод ссылок и картинок в комментариях

Tags: веб-программирование, регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите, пожалуйста, с регулярными выражениями. Пытаюсь сделать вывод ссылок и картинок в комментариях, первую часть по выводу ссылок я сделал, как теперь сделать так, чтобы, если url имеет путь к картинке, её отображать. Т. е. привести к виду: `if(ссылка){отображаем линк}elseif(картинка){выводим картинку <img src... и т. д.}`

```
function hrefCallback($lnk) {
  $name = htmlspecialchars($lnk[0]);
  $href = !empty($lnk[1])? $name : "http://$name";
  return "<a href=\"$href\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"linka\" rel=\"nofollow\">$name</a>";
}

function hreftolink($text) {
  return preg_replace_callback('{(?:(\w+://) | www\.)[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*(?: : \d+)?[^<>"\'()\[\]\s]*(?:(?<! [[:punct:]] ) | (?<= [-/&+*]))}xis',"hrefCallback",$text);
}
```

Помогите разобраться с задачкой, потом хочу использовать дополнительно для отображения видео с youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать определять по расширению файлов .jpg, .png и прочих, но не факт, что на том конце окажется изображение.

```
$bits = explode('.', $link);
$lastBit = $bits[sizeof($bits) - 1];
if (in_array($lastBit, array('png', 'jpeg', 'jpg',))) {
    // предположительно изображение
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пропущен первый параметр функции explode(). Должно быть так:

```
$bits = explode('.',$link);
```

Хотя, расширение файла можно получить и таким образом:

```
$ext = pathinfo($link, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(in_array($ext, array('png', 'jpeg', 'jpg',))) {
    // предположительно изображение
}
```

Также желательно проверять MIME-тип файла:

```
$finfo = new finfo;
$type = $finfo->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

Comment: все равно беда, ссылки появляются как надо, а вот картинка печаль, выглядит так в исходном коде <img src="<a href=\" http:="" skrin.at.ua="" _nw="" 0="" 85512853.jpg\"="" target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" class="\&quot;linka\&quot;" rel="\&quot;nofollow\&quot;">skrin.at.ua" align="center" width="400" height="" /&gt;

Comment: нет, не беда, сделал как хотел, но подсказка копать в сторону мим-типов была полезна, теперь работает как и задумывалось